# List.JS - Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, listjs

I cannot seem to figure this out. I've already tried $(document).ready and still doesn't work for me. I've also tried making a for loop specifically for these two value names to save the results to a var and pass it in that way. I've also tried putting the input with the class and id with search inside of the parent div and outside. Essentially like it in the nav bar. Using list.js & knockout.js btw. Im getting my venues using an ajax request using foursquares api.

JS:

```
        var options = {
        valueNames: ['name', 'category']
    };

    var userList = new List('search', options);
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<nav>
    <h1 class="formattedH1">Downtown SA,TX</h1>
    <span>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="search" id="search">
      <input type="button" class="sort searchButton" value="List"></input>
    </span>
</nav>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div class="list">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="search" id="search">
    <h1>My Top 5</h1>
    <!-- Square card -->
    <div class="card" id="favViewModel" data-bind="foreach: favList">
        <div class="expand">
            <h2 class="venueName" data-bind="text:name"></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="cardSupport" data-bind="attr: {src: image()}">
        </div>
        <div class="cardSupport" data-bind="text:address">
        </div>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: website()}">Website</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Foursquare Recommended</h1>
    <div class="card" id="recViewModel" data-bind="foreach: recommendedSpotList  ">
        <div class="expand">
            <h2 class="venueName" data-bind="text:name"></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="cardSupport" data-bind="text:location">
        </div>
        <div class="cardSupport" data-bind="text:category">
        </div>
        <div class="cardSupport" data-bind="text:rating">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/tester123.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer browsing other similar projects, so simple now. Thought it might help someone in case they ran across this. It was that since I was making an ajax call I had to to place the call to ko.applybindings inside the ajax request. The binding was out of scope, if you think about it make's sense especially if your request fails. Why even attempt to still bind the values of the request. HTML as above, and for JS ajax request please see below:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'data',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {

        venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];

        //This is where I had to place the binding to get it to render properly.
        ko.applyBindings(new recommendedViewModel(), document.getElementById('recViewModel'));

    },
    error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

I fixed the same problem with some comments on the github page of the project, just make sure to have the same names as the examples and it will work, everything must be in a `<div>` and the `ul` must have the `class` **list**

Like this

```
<div id="hacker-list">
   <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Link: https://github.com/javve/list.js/issues/9

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the list class on the ul element. Had me stumped for ages!

Comment: Adding the class "list" works for me where insted of use a ul list, is a div container.

Comment: Also, when defining a `new List('users', options)`, make sure your `#users` div wraps _both_ the input/buttons and the actual ordered/unordered list (as seen on the https://listjs.com homepage).

Comment: If you still have the same error after adding the class name `list`. Make the class name `list` as the first among the class names for the element.

Answer (score 0):

**"Hello World"** example of this error.

**Where?**

https://listjs.com/api/#listClass

**listClass** String, default: "**list**" What is the class of the
list-container.

### Case one (Missing `list` class):

```css
/* error example */
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

```html
<!-- error example -->
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul data-missing-list-class class="">
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">John</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

### Case two (custom `listClass` missing):

I declare listClass to be `no_such_class`. The code trying to read `childNodes` of undefined.

```css
/* error example */
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
  listClass: "no_such_class" /* the error */
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
```

```html
<!-- error example -->
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">No such class</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

**the error will not throw under stackoverflow snippet

#### Extra

Remember to not confuse between:

**id or element**

> Id the element in which the list area should be initialized. OR the
> actual element itself.

`new List(id/element, options, values);`

VS:
**listClass**
What is the class of the list-container?